# Angular: reference currently instantiated controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, self-reference, lexical-scope

Is there a way to get reference to the currently instantiated controller object from within the controller's definition? I'd like to `$compile` a modal and bind that to the same controller that's creating the modal.

Here's a simplified version of what I'd like to do, where `THIS_CONTROLLER_INSTANCE` is a reference to my controller instance.

```
angular.module('foo')
.controller('barController', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.openModal = function(){
    var modalEl = $('<div class="modal">Modal stuff here</div>');
    var controller = THIS_CONTROLLER_INSTANCE;
    modalEl.contents().data('$ngControllerController', THIS_CONTROLLER_INSTANCE);

    $compile(modalEl)($scope);
    $('body').append(modalEl);
  }
});
```

Comment: The controller is defined in the dom with the `ng-controller` directive, so it wouldn't be under `$route`, unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried using "this" I'm not sure it will work but worth a shot.

Comment: Yup, `this` is a $scope object

Comment: what about console.log(this) before the openModal function

Comment: Actually, `this` in the controller definition is the instantiated controller! Not sure why I didn't think of that before. Case closed. Will edit my post above

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> The current controller is `this`. So the solution to my problem is:

```
angular.module('foo')
.controller('barController', function($scope, $rootScope){
  var self = this;
  $scope.openModal = function(){
    var modalEl = $('<div class="modal">Modal stuff here</div>');
    var controller = self;
    modalEl.contents().data('$ngControllerController', controller);

    $compile(modalEl)($scope);
    $('body').append(modalEl);
  }
});
```